# Reveal.js export and code block output

Tags: org-export

I'd like to use `ATTR_REVEAL: :frag (roll-in)` to display images in a reveal.js slideshow that are created using `dot` source blocks.

So far I've tried source block headings of:

`#+BEGIN_SRC dot :file test.png :results show :exports results`
This shows the test.png in the slideshow, but doesn't roll it in

`#+BEGIN_SRC dot :file test.png :results none :exports results`
This does not show test.png in the slideshow

`#+BEGIN_SRC dot :file test.png :exports none`
This does not show test.png in the slideshow either.

Is what i'm trying to do here possible? If so, what heading parameters should I use to export to the reveal.js slideshow?

Here is the slideshow source if it helps you understand things:

```
#+REVEAL_THEME: sky
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil num:nil
#+TITLE: Cool title
#+AUTHOR: That guy

* Slide 1
#+ATTR_REVEAL: :frag (roll-in)
- List item 1
#+BEGIN_SRC dot :file test1.png :results show :exports results
digraph auth {
rankdir=LR;
node [shape=record];
1->2;
2->3;
3->1 [label="bleh!", fontcolor=red];
}
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: [[file:test1.png]]

- List item 2
#+BEGIN_SRC dot :file test2.png :results none :exports results
graph pres {
rankdir=LR;
node [shape=record];

1--2--3--4;
}
#+END_SRC

* Slide 2
* Slide 3
```

Comment: just a question, would removing the space between the src_block and the results change anything? Try checking the exported html for hints. Maybe the space makes the file land in another element?

Answer (score 2):

Figured out the solution. To get the `#+RESULTS` to `roll-in` during the exported presentation, I had to add additional `#+ATTR_REVEAL :frag (roll-in)` headings above each.

Corrected source:

```
#+REVEAL_THEME: sky
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil num:nil
#+TITLE: Cool title
#+AUTHOR: That guy

* Slide 1
#+ATTR_REVEAL: :frag (roll-in)
- List item 1

#+BEGIN_SRC dot :file test1.png
digraph auth {
rankdir=LR;
node [shape=record];
1->2;
2->3;
3->1 [label="bleh!", fontcolor=red];
}
#+END_SRC

#+ATTR_REVEAL: :frag (roll-in)
#+RESULTS: [[file:test1.png]]

#+ATTR_REVEAL: :frag (roll-in)
- List item 2

#+BEGIN_SRC dot :file test2.png
graph pres {
rankdir=LR;
node [shape=record];
1--2--3--4;
}
#+END_SRC

#+ATTR_REVEAL: :frag (roll-in)
#+RESULTS: file:test2.png

* Slide 2
* Slide 3
```

Hope this helps someone else too!